# Trigger que actualize un campo despues de una insercion - ORACLE

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-18c

este trigger se realiza sobre la base de datos HR que viene por defecto en ORACLE XE. Se requiere que despues de INSERTAR nueva fila en la tabla de empleados si no se pone el correo se asigne uno tomando en cuenta el nombre y apellido del empleado. La columna de EMAIL dentro de EMPLOYEES no admite valores nulos por lo cual hipoteticamente el no insertar un correo seria poner un '-'. Realice un intento de codigo el cual muestro a continuacion. Agradeceria su ayuda.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CREATE_EMAIL_IF_NULL
AFTER INSERT ON EMPLOYEES
DECLARE
NOMBRE EMPLOYEES.FIRST_NAME%TYPE;
APELLIDO EMPLOYEES.LAST_NAME%TYPE;
EMAIL_REPLACE VARCHAR2(25);
BEGIN
    
    SELECT EMAIL INTO EMAIL_REPLACE FROM EMPLOYEES;
    IF(EMAIL_REPLACE = '-') THEN
        SELECT FIRST_NAME INTO NOMBRE FROM EMPLOYEES;
        SELECT LAST_NAME INTO APELLIDO FROM EMPLOYEES;
        EMAIL_REPLACE := (NOMBRE ||''||APELLIDO);
        INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES (EMAIL) VALUES (EMAIL_REPLACE);
    END IF;
    END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para afectar el registro que se está insertando, utiliza un trigger `before insert`, que se lanza justo antes de que los datos se almacenen en la tabla, lo que te da la oportunidad de manipularlos de la manera que se te está pidiendo.

En este trigger, los datos que se han asignado a los campos de la tabla están en el pseudo-registro `new`, que tiene la misma estructura de la tabla.

El trigger se dispara una vez por cada registro que se inserta, así que debes lidiar con un único registro cada vez.

Te dejo un ejemplo, que no hace lo que te piden en el ejercicio, pues eso debes hacerlo tu, pero si te dejará en la dirección correcta

```
create or replace trigger employees_assign_email
before insert on employees for each row
begin    
  if :new.email = '-' then
    :new.email := :new.first_name || '@miempresa.com';
  end if;
end;
```